# Registration Form Validation in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, user-registration

I have validate the custom field in registration form, I read out the codex of wordpress so that itself i do this way. But I figure out it throws error like this one

```
Call to a member function add() on a non-object  I don't know why this should happen. How can i overcome this.
```

**Code:**

```
function myplugin_check_fields($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {

        $errors->add( 'demo_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: This is a demo error. Registration halted.','mydomain') );

        return $errors;

    }

    add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this might be a bug in a plug-in or theme. From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors#Examples):

> The form will not create a new user if any errors are returned. Notice: **The function must return the variable $errors in any case** (even when there is no error in your logic), **otherwise the function may cause this problem: *Fatal error: Call to a member function `get_error_code()` on a non-object.***

Deactivate all other plug-ins to find which is causing it. If it's still persisting, switch the theme to TwentyEeven. Once you've identified the culprit, you'll need to search the code for the error - somewhere they'll be doing something similar to you, but *not* returning `$errors`.