# What is the Object for WP_Error Class?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development

i want to know what is the **object** for `WP_Error` Class located in **wp-includes/class-wp-error.php** because i used a custom registration form plugin in there for validation i used this below function

```
 function custom_validation($errors) {

            if (($_POST['birthday']) != 1)
                $errors->add('birthday', "<strong>ERROR</strong>:" . please finish birthday);

      return $errors;
    }

add_filter('registration_errors', array('customregistration', 'custom_validation'), 10, 3);
```

Above function works fine with WordPress default themes(twentytwelve,twentyeleven). but if i use with other themes on registration it shows `Call to a member function add() on a non-object`

So i searched for $errors object in `WP_Error` Class but i couldn't able to see a `new` keyword which is used to create an object for a class.

Now

1. what is the object for `WP_Error` Class?
2. if it is $errors then why am i facing a fatal error called `Call to a member function add() on a non-object`?
3. i can't able to see a class instance in `WP_Error` by using `new`
   keyword.
4. if it not $errors how this is working in default theme?

**Note**:Other theme registration page looks different from default registration page.

Comment: Where are you calling `custom_validation()`, is hooked onto something?

Comment: `registration_errors` @Stephen Harris

Comment: the phrase "what is the object for WP_Error class" makes no sense, it is equivilant to "what is the object for an object"? which doesn't make sense either. Perhaps you need to find out where custom_validation is being called from, is it a hook or a filter?

Comment: I am usind Filter `registration_errors`.... can you please refer the instance of WP-Error class @Tom J Nowell

Comment: @raj, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111130/registration-form-validation-in-wordpress - I think my answer there is what you're after.

Comment: @Stephen Harris the problem must be in theme not with plugin because when i use with twentytwelve theme there is no bug.but if i use my custom theme i'm getting error **Call to a member function add() on a non-object** that is why i asked what is the instance for the class WP_Error located in wp-includes/class-wp-error.php because i can't able to see new keyword used to create object

Comment: Raj can you post the surrounding code that adds the filter?

Comment: @Raj, my linked answer applies to themes as well. You'll need to find the bug in theme and fix it. The `$errors` object is filtered, and the theme isn't returning it, so by the time it reaches your code `$errors` is `NULL`. This is a bug in the theme.

Comment: @Stephen Harris yes i can getting that, but i just want to know where is the `new` keyword with a object $errors in WP_Error class it is not there.i just want to know that where it is Instantiated?. May be i am thinking wrongly about object if so advice me

Comment: @Tom J Nowell see my edits for hook details and surrounded code

Comment: @raj, its instantiated here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-login.php#L322

Comment: @Stephen Harris Wow,i never thought about this.i searched $errors only in class-wp-error.php. so looks like they have created different object for the same class in different function with access to that function alone and given us API.Am i clear?

Comment: @raj it sounds like you're confusing defining a class and creating an object

Comment: @Tom j Nowell  [HERE](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-login.php#L322) in line 48 $wp_error is object for WP_Error and in line 202 $errors is object for same class WP_Error.am saying $wp_error and $errors are object for class WP_Error.is this correct?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your english well enough. You need to improve your grammar. Sentences begin with capital letters, always put spaces after full stops, use the ` code formatting for class names

Comment: @Tom j Nowell Thanks. Apart from my english what i pointed out was correct or not? B'coz i want to know where am i in OOP?

Comment: I don't know because I'm not sure what you were trying to say

Comment: hmm if you mean are they objects of type `WP_Error`, then yes they are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10274/discussion-between-raj-and-tom-j-nowell)